# Split string after variable amount of characters

Tags: c#, .net

I want to split my string called: invoerstring after a variable amount of characters (n is the number of characters when the string needs to be split)..
 If the string length is shorter then the variable n, spaces need to be added until the string    length = n. The result needs to be shown in a textfield called uitvoer.

This is what so far:

```
string invoerstring = invoer.Text;

if (invoerstring.Length < n)
{
    invoerstring += "";
    char[] myStrChars = invoerstring.ToCharArray();
}

if (invoerstring.Length == n)
{
    string [] blok = invoerstring.Split();
    foreach (string word in blok)
    {
        uitvoer.Text = word;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The solutions given above aren't completely doing the job for me, maybe it helps when I post the exercise:

> || crypt n m d text || text is padded with spaces until its length is
>   a multiple of n || the characters in text are circulary shifted in the
>   alphabet by the displacement d || example: if d = 1 then 'a' -> 'b' ,
>   'b' -> 'c' .... etc... 'z' -> 'a' || text is divided in blocks of
>   length n characters || inside every block of n the characters are
>   circulary shifted m times to the left || the shifted groups are
>   concatenated

I already solved the m and d only have to solve the n.

---

The solutions given above aren't completely doing the job for me, maybe it helps when I post the exercise:

|| crypt n m d text
||   text is padded with spaces until its length is a multiple of n
||   the characters in text are circulary shifted in the alphabet by the displacement d 
||   example: if d = 1 then 'a' -> 'b' ,  'b' -> 'c' .... etc... 'z' -> 'a' 
||   text is divided in blocks of length n characters
||   inside every block of n  the characters are circulary shifted m times to the left 
||   the shifted groups are concatenated

I already solved the m and d only have to solve the n.

Comment: I don't see any "?", so what is the question?

Comment: A couple things I see right off the bat that should help you, regardless of what your actual problem is that you're only checking if the length is less than N once. Change that first if to a while. Second, you're only checking if the length is exactly equal. Change the == in the second if to >=

Comment: I'd also recommend to rename certain things before posting here. Imagine you would have written `string a = textBox1.Text` << this way you don't need to explain what is `textBox1` and `a`, because it is clear and *usual*.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code you want, no need to go through a character array:

```
public static string EnsureExactLength(this string s, int length)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("null");

    return s.PadRight(length).Substring(0, length);
}
```

You call it like this:

```
string s = "Test string".EnsureExactLength(4); // will return "Test"
string s = "Te".EnsureExactLength(4);          // will return "Te  "
```

You can find an example [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w98zsn5kb09on53/SO16963484.linq).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm honestly not sure what the code you have above is doing because I see calls like `Split()` without any parameters, and stuff. But to meet the requirements, this one line should do:

```
string invoerstring = invoer.Text.PadRight(n, ' ').Substring(0, n);
```

the `PadRight` will make sure it's **as long as `n`** and the `Substring` will then return the portion of the `string` up to `n`.

If you then wanted that string in an array, because I see you have one at the end, you could do this:

```
invoerstring.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a LinqPad script:

```
void Main()
{
    const string TEXT = "12345ABCDE12345ABCDE1234";
    const int LENGTH = 5;
    const char PAD = '#';

    Enumerable.Range(0, TEXT.Length / LENGTH)
        .Union(TEXT.Length < LENGTH ? new int[] { 1 } : new int[] {})
        .Select((index, item) => TEXT.Length < LENGTH 
                                    ? TEXT.PadRight(LENGTH, PAD)
                                    : TEXT.Substring(index * LENGTH, LENGTH))
        .Concat(TEXT.Length % LENGTH != 0 
                    ? new string[] { TEXT.Substring(TEXT.Length - (TEXT.Length % LENGTH)).PadRight(LENGTH, PAD) }
                    : new string[] { })                                 
        .Dump();

}
```